# How to make a new solution with projects of other solution in GitHub?

Tags: c#, github, repository

I have an application created in VisualStudio 2013 with C#
In GitHub I have the folder with projects:

Business/app1
-project1
-project2
-project3
-project4
-mainProject
-app.sln

And I need to create another application which needs to use project1, project2, project3 and project4.

How could I do to use it and then , when I need to sync this new solution, the posibility to push/pull all at the same time?

I mean, I need this:

Business/app2
- mainProject2
- project1
- project2
- project3
- project4
- app2.sln

Thanks!

Comment: are you using visual studio?

Comment: yees! I'm using VS2013

Answer (score 0):

VS offers the option "add a project from sourcecontrol".

You can find it under "File -> Source Control -> extended/extras -> add project from sourcecontrol".

There you can choose which project you would like to add.